# IOS app stuck in white screen when deployed to Testflight expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

SDK Version: ^43.0.0
Platform: IOS

I am building a react-native app on mac mini with M1 chip
The IOS app is built using “expo build:ios” command and it is successful
I am able to upload the archive to the apple appstore using “transporter”
When I open the app on my mobile phone through TestFlight, the screen is blank.

When I run expo start everything works fine locally